# Apache rights in my home folders

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ubuntu-10.04

I got a dedicated server running Ubuntu 10.04 with 10 users. Weeks ago i configure Apache with Alias for each user, everyone got a www/ inside their own /home/ and i pointed a subdomain to each www/

```
Alias /foo /home/foo/www/
    <Directory /home/foo/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

It works well to regular website but when i want to use some shell_exec with PHP i got some rights issues.
Apache don't got the sufficient right to write in the folder.
I tried to add www-data group to the www/ & to grant my users with the www-data rights but it does not work...

Here is a the ls -a command result

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 foo www-data  4096 2012-07-24 08:44 www/
```

Any clue to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the *userdir* module in Apache for this, instead.

It allows Apache access to a specific directory in your users' home directory - by default

```
/home/foo/public_html
```

http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/ has a pretty good guide on how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

With your current permission-scheme on the www-folder, the `www-data`-group only got read and execute permissions on the directory. Give it write-permissions with the following command:

```
chmod 0775 www
```

If the directory contains more directories and you need to apply new permissions recursively, you can run the following commands:

```
find www -type d -exec chmod 0775 '{}' \;
find www -type f -exec chmod 0664 '{}' \;
```

Comment: Yeah, i also tought to do it that way but i'm a bit afraid to give write rights to groups ... Especially on a production environnement.

Comment: You have to if you want Apache to write to those directories. If possible, you should limit this write-access only to what is absolutely necessary.